# strip html tags from an xpath @attribute

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to extract some text from a webpage using lxml and xpath - there are two bits I need

the main text body:

```
page = requests.get(url)
pageopen = lxml.html.fromstring(page)

body_one = pageopen.xpath('/html/body//div/div/div//div/p[@class="body"]/text()')
```

which is working fine

The second body of text (which only reveals after a mouse click) I have managed to get using

```
pageopen.xpath('/html/body//div/div/div//div//span/@data-description')
```

but the text returned still has html junk in it.

Using the /text() function on the above statement returns an empty list.

I've spent hours reading the lxml documentation but its all Greek to me.

How do I strip html tags from an xpath @attribute?

Comment: First off, check if you can reduce the first xpath to `//p[@class="body"]/text()`. You're making it too complicated. The second one, confirm that it's not using Javascript to get the value of the tag. If it doesn't just strip it using `fromstring` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the text returned still has html junk in it

If you mean that the string is HTML, use the technique you already understand for extracting text from HTML:

```
descriptionHtml = pageopen.xpath('/html/body//div/div/div//div//span/@data-description')
descriptionBody = lxml.html.fromstring(descriptionHtml)
descriptionText = descriptionBody.xpath('text()')
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I just had to select the first element:  descriptionHtml = pageopen.xpath('/html/body//div/div/div//div//span/@data-description')[0] otherwise it threw an error

Comment: Why does this method remove numbers in the text?